# What is this を doing here?

Tags: grammar, particles

For full context, see the document: 
https://www.docdroid.net/qteAJpo/img-20170628-0002-new.pdf.html

The sentence in question:
成功した自分と雑誌の記者**を**一人でやるのです。
I understand it as follows: 
"I do on my own

my successful self with a journalist from a magazine"

I set the second part apart because I didnt use any connective structures in my translation now. I did it because there are none in the japanese original and I don't know which extrapolation might be correct here.

I interpreted the part before the bold を basically as one sentence element, which on the level of the complete sentence would be the direct object of やる. 
However, this probably would require some other elements in the sentence right?
Maybe someone could show me what would have to be put in?^^

Here's how I think the sentence could be translated as well:
"I do/act on my own **as if** my successful self was with a journalist of a magazine."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 成功した自分と雑誌の記者を一人でやるのです。

"I play the roles of both my successful self and the journalist of a magazine, on my own / just by myself."

The （～を）やる here means （役を）演じる, "play the role of..." "act as..."

---

> this probably would require some other elements...

The sentence makes perfect sense by itself, but if you want to make it clearer, you could rephrase it as...

> 成功した自分と雑誌の記者**の役**を一人でやるのです。